# print different text on checkbox check/uncheck with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am creating a web app in which i am using toggle button when a user click once on the toggle button `'yes'` should be store in a `$scope` variable if the user click twice `'no'` should be stored in a `$scope` variable

here is my codding for toggle button

```
<div class="switch">
     <input ng-click="clickcheckbox()" id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
     <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
 </div>
```

i have taken `ng-click` because i am not able to do this with `ng-checked`

here is my controller

```
$scope.clickcheckbox=function(){
    //if user check the checkbox
    $scope.check='yes';
    //if user uncheck the checkbox
    $scope.check='no';
    }
```

if there are other better ways to do this(please help me out with them)

Comment: Use ng-change directive to track the changes, and ng-model to store the value in a $scope property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.clickcheckbox=function(){
    $scope.check=='yes'? $scope.check='no': $scope.check='yes';     
}
```

Inh HTML:

```
<div class="switch" ng-init="check='yes'">
     <input  ng-click="clickcheckbox()" id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
     <label for="cmn-toggle-1">{{check}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"
           ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
```

javascript:

```
$scope.checkboxModel = { 
       value2 : 'YES'
     };
```

Where:

```
ngTrueValue  : The value to which the expression should be set when selected.

ngFalseValue : The value to which the expression should be set when not selected.
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rno1fnct/)

[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work.

```
$scope.clickcheckbox = function() {
    if($scope.check == undefined || $scope.check = 'no') {
        $scope.check = 'yes';
    } else {
         $scope.check = 'no';
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, a common way to deals with checkboxes and boolean values is do to the following:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="check = !check">
```

Here, each click will revert the value between `true` and `false`.